# How do I find a product name from a product key?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I get individual labels (names) for different products keys? I want to detect the product key and based on that assign the right product name to it.

If it was just one product key in question, this could be easily done using `IF` function as in `IF(H2="Product Key","Product Name")` but there are many product keys.

The project is to scan a barcode and pull up its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by pnuts, you could solve this with the VLOOKUP function.

Create a list of all your products and their keys:

```
  | Column A       | Column B         |
---------------------------------------
1 | Product key    | Product name     | 
2 | 1234567890001  | Corn Flakes      |
3 | 1234567890002  | Coco Pops        |
4 | 1234567890003  | Special K        |
5 | 1234567890004  | All-Bran         |
6 | 1234567890005  | Rice Crispies    |
```

Now, anywhere else in your spreadsheet, let's say cell `G4`, create a formula

```
=VLOOKUP(G3; A2:B6; 2; false)
```

Then, in cell `G3`, try to enter a valid product key. `G4` should now display the corresponding product name.

The `VLOOKUP` function first takes an input value (from cell `G3`), then a list of keys and values (`A2:B6`), then a boolean specifying if the list is sorted or not, which we for now can leave at `false`.

I have set up [an example spreadsheet to demonstrate](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1se3Q0rMLH8syJqhzAjgReGv62clUgzdGJ7ko-V5GSrI/edit?usp=sharing), feel free to copy it for your own experimentation. Also, see the [documentation for VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

Comment: Thanks alot Vidar. I have done it successfully. A new challenge has come up. I am trying to deduct one unit of stock for every email the following email labels "sold", "reserved","internal damaged","manufacturer damaged","unfulfillable", etc. As explained, Can you help me with a script that counts every time a certain label is received im my inbox?

Comment: Maybe I can, and maybe someone else can. In either case, post that as a separate question. You can link to this question if that helps make the context clearer.

Comment: And if this answer helped you, you could _accept_ (by clicking the checkmark) and/or _upvote_ it.

Comment: I did so thanks again, i'm so new here. And here's my separate question link: Please kindly help if you will: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/107444/email-label-triggers-google-sheets